# Grunt + Sass, how do I include subfolder scss when I compile?

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

I'm trying to change my sass workflow by including it in grunt and compiling from there.  I can compile successfully if all my scss files are in one folder:

```
sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compact'
            },
            files: {
                'style.css': 'css/*.scss'
            }
        }
    }
```

however my usual file structure includes a subfolder for components exclusive to certain pages.  Grunt is recognising the top level .scss files but nothing below it.  I also tried this:

```
        sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compact'
            },
            files: {
                'style.css': 'css/main.scss',
                'style.css': 'css/pages/*.scss'
            }
        }
    }
```

but no joy there either.  How do I compile to a single css file from multiple scss locations?

Comment: one way is to use [concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) to concatenate the scss files into one giant one then compiling that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add `/**/` after your folder, like so:

```
'style.css': 'css/**/*.scss'
```

You can see the documentation here: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns